# How different have the various constitutions of Venezuela been?

Tags: constitution, venezuela, comparative-politics

From [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/33623/9453) to a related question, I have learned that Venezuela has had 27 Constitutions.

As an American, who have only had one (or two, if you count the Articles of Confederation) this seems to be high to me. On the other hand, the American Constitution has been amended 18 or 27 times (depending on how one counts, as the first ten were ratified effectively simultaneously, given the transportation and communication channels of the time period).

Therefore, I ask **how different have Venezuela's Constitutions been to one another and on average, how big has scope of their changes been?**

Comment: The last one has the benefit of being totally ignored by the Socialists in power

Comment: From that other answer, "I think was the twenty-fifth constitution of Venezuela". That seems high to me. Venezuela's had numerous revisions, but [not that many](http://constitutionnet.org/country/constitutional-history-venezuela): 1811, 1830, 1858, 1863, 1893, 1901, 1914, 1946, 1953, 1961, 1999, and the on-going one. Of those, only four-ish (depending upon how you count) have been "major revisions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How different have the various constitutions of Venezuela been?

Rather difficult to say, but apparently many of the constitutions were quite similar.

[Venezuela, Constitutions](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/venezuela-constitutions)

> Venezuela has had twenty-seven constitutions since 1811, the most recent of which was promulgated in 1999. Why this apparent surfeit of constitutions for a country that was dominated by *caudillos*<sup>1</sup> and military elites throughout much of its independent history? Owing to chronic instability, virtually every new regime sought to declare its independence from predecessor regimes by writing a new constitution. In the Spanish American tradition, instead of adding amendments or changing specific provisions, an entirely new constitution was enacted, even if very little of substance was actually changed. In the nineteenth century two of the main changes dealt with the balance between centralism and federalism, and expansion or retraction of the suffrage. One feature of Venezuela's constitutional history has remained constant, however: Venezuelan government is essentially presidentialist. Even the most recent and most democratic constitution—that of 1999—provides for a powerful chief executive who can assume extraordinary powers.
>
> The first constitution of the new Republic of Gran Colombia, written in 1811, was inspired by the U.S. Constitution and the French Declaration of the Rights of Man and clearly reflects the thinking of an educated oligarchy. It provided for a weak central government and placed literacy requirements on suffrage and property-holding requirements on officeholding. The Angostura Constitution of 1819, reacting against excessive federalism, strengthened the power of the executive and central authority. In 1830, after breaking away from Gran Colombia, Venezuela promulgated its own constitution, which reflected a compromise between unitary and federalist government. Between 1830 and 1900 eight constitutions were written, effecting slight changes in the balance of power between the federal government and the states.

The balance of the article discusses the changes in some of the constitutions since 1864.

---

<sup>1</sup> a military or political leader